# STM32G474 FDCAN Callback is not called. Classic frame

Tags: stm32, can, stm32cubeide

I have a custom board with an STM32G474RE. I use 3 CANs with 3 independent CAN tranciever on the board.

I tried sendind CAN message from CAN1 to CAN3 but the message is not received. At least the callback funnction is not called. I used an oscilloscope to make sure that the message was sent by CAN1 and received on CAN3 pins.

I used the STM CANFD example codes. Unfortunately they use CANFD format and Classical. Maybe that is where I made a mistake.
I am sure that problem is somewhere in the filtering. Unfortunately I can't find any good example for classical frame FDCAN.  When I comment out the HAL_FDCAN_ConfigGlobalFilter() the code is working. Without the filtering of course. How should I config the filter to accept for example the 0x201 Id?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
FDCAN_RxHeaderTypeDef RxHeader;
uint8_t RxData[8];
FDCAN_TxHeaderTypeDef TxHeader;
uint8_t TxData[8] = {0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88};

void MX_FDCAN3_Init(void)
{

  hfdcan3.Instance = FDCAN3;
  hfdcan3.Init.FrameFormat = FDCAN_FRAME_CLASSIC;
  hfdcan3.Init.Mode = FDCAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hfdcan3.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hfdcan3.Init.TransmitPause = DISABLE;
  hfdcan3.Init.ProtocolException = DISABLE;
  hfdcan3.Init.NominalPrescaler = 21;
  hfdcan3.Init.NominalSyncJumpWidth = 1;
  hfdcan3.Init.NominalTimeSeg1 = 5;
  hfdcan3.Init.NominalTimeSeg2 = 2;
  hfdcan3.Init.DataPrescaler = 21;
  hfdcan3.Init.DataSyncJumpWidth = 1;
  hfdcan3.Init.DataTimeSeg1 = 5;
  hfdcan3.Init.DataTimeSeg2 = 2;
  hfdcan3.Init.StdFiltersNbr = 0;
  hfdcan3.Init.ExtFiltersNbr = 0;
  hfdcan3.Init.TxFifoQueueMode = FDCAN_TX_FIFO_OPERATION;
  if (HAL_FDCAN_Init(&hfdcan3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

FDCAN Config

```
void FDCAN_Config(void)
{
  FDCAN_FilterTypeDef sFilterConfig;

  /* Configure Rx filter */
  sFilterConfig.IdType = FDCAN_STANDARD_ID;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIndex = 0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterType = FDCAN_FILTER_DUAL;
  sFilterConfig.FilterConfig = FDCAN_FILTER_TO_RXFIFO0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterID1 = 0x201;
  sFilterConfig.FilterID2 = 0x7FF;

  if (HAL_FDCAN_ConfigFilter(&hfdcan1, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_FDCAN_ConfigFilter(&hfdcan3, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
//
//  /* Configure global filter:
//     Filter all remote frames with STD and EXT ID
//     Reject non matching frames with STD ID and EXT ID */
  if (HAL_FDCAN_ConfigGlobalFilter(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_REJECT, FDCAN_REJECT, FDCAN_FILTER_REMOTE, FDCAN_FILTER_REMOTE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_FDCAN_ConfigGlobalFilter(&hfdcan3, FDCAN_REJECT, FDCAN_REJECT, FDCAN_FILTER_REMOTE, FDCAN_FILTER_REMOTE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* Start the FDCAN module */
  if (HAL_FDCAN_Start(&hfdcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_FDCAN_Start(&hfdcan3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_FDCAN_ActivateNotification(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_NEW_MESSAGE, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_FDCAN_ActivateNotification(&hfdcan3, FDCAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_NEW_MESSAGE, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* Prepare Tx Header */
  TxHeader.Identifier = 0x201;
  TxHeader.IdType = FDCAN_STANDARD_ID;
  TxHeader.TxFrameType = FDCAN_FRAME_CLASSIC;
  TxHeader.DataLength = FDCAN_DLC_BYTES_8;
  TxHeader.ErrorStateIndicator = FDCAN_ESI_ACTIVE;
  TxHeader.BitRateSwitch = FDCAN_BRS_OFF;
  TxHeader.FDFormat = FDCAN_CLASSIC_CAN;
  TxHeader.TxEventFifoControl = FDCAN_NO_TX_EVENTS;
  TxHeader.MessageMarker = 0;
}
```

main.c

````
.
.
.
  FDCAN_Config();
  while (1){
      if (HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxFifoQ(&hfdcan3, &TxHeader, TxData) != HAL_OK)
      {
        /* Transmission request Error */
        Error_Handler();
      }
      HAL_Delay(500);
  }


-------

void HAL_FDCAN_RxFifo0Callback(FDCAN_HandleTypeDef *hfdcan, uint32_t RxFifo0ITs)
{

    if(FDCAN1 == hfdcan->Instance){

          if((RxFifo0ITs & FDCAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_NEW_MESSAGE) != RESET)
          {
            /* Retrieve Rx messages from RX FIFO0 */
            if (HAL_FDCAN_GetRxMessage(hfdcan, FDCAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxHeader, RxData) != HAL_OK)
            {
            Error_Handler();
            }

            /* Display LEDx */
            if ((RxHeader.Identifier == 0x201) && (RxHeader.IdType == FDCAN_STANDARD_ID))
            {
                HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_10);
            }
          }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I don't know these libs but is `FilterID2 = 0x7FF;` supposed to set the acceptance mask? I tried to check the bloatware manual but it doesn't mention what these are for, nor what "dual" filter is supposed to do. You have to read the MCU manual regarding these settings.

Comment: Also your baudrate settings are questionable. You should set the sample point at 87.5% if possible. Your current setting uses 75% with (5+1)/8 tq. Ideal is (13+1)/16 tq. What kind of system clock are you using and how accurate is it?

Comment: I am using 16MHz currently from the internal oscillator. I have a 24MHz external oscillator on the board. I tried it in my car and it was working with these settings.
When the ConfigGlobalFilter() is called it does not receive any message. I tried many different settings. Also tried FDCAN_FILTER_MASK instead of dual acceptance. In that case the FilterID2 = 0x7FF is the acceptance mask.

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet? I think I've the same issue, without filttering everything work well, but when I add config global filtter interrupt doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem just now. The problem ist, your are configuring a filter with `HAL_FDCAN_ConfigFilter`, but this filter never gets active because you have the line `hfdcan3.Init.StdFiltersNbr = 0;`. This number needs to be greater or equal to the number you are using.

And since `HAL_FDCAN_ConfigGlobalFilter(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_REJECT, FDCAN_REJECT, FDCAN_FILTER_REMOTE, FDCAN_FILTER_REMOTE)` is active nothing gets received.